Upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04.1 but gnome is still 42
I've been attempting to upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 I received a pop-up message for the upgrade, but it failed midway. Now, when I check the version, it shows 24.04.1, but the only thing that seems to have been upgraded is the desktop background image. The GNOME version is still 42.9.

Thanks for your help.
Here is the output of sudo apt update :


It may help if you're specific with details and what happened. You mention it failed midway, but you've then note said what you did.  Did you attempt to restart the release-upgrade?? what part of the upgrade was it up to (I assume downloading packages was done, and it was installing, if so I'd get it to continue the package upgrades... What did you do?  Have you rebooted?  Have you run sudo apt update & explored what is there, attempted a apt full-upgrade etc?  I'd also do all this from terminal & only use GUI after upgrade had completed...).   What exactly happened?

I received the upgrade message for Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. When I clicked on upgrade, it downloaded the new version but couldn't install it properly. Even though it said it would disable the third-party PPA, it gave an error related to the third-party PPA. Now, when checking the version, it shows as 24.04.1, but the GNOME version is still 42.9.

I have already tried the apt update & full-upgrade

If you read what I put, I mentioned apt update and then said explored what is there, ie. it wasn't just that the command ran, that all lines of output were what they should be, no missing lines etc.. (alternatively just explore your sources to ensure they're correct)... The subsequent command apt full-upgrade is of no value if there were problems (extra lines, missing lines etc) in the first apt update command. Were the sources all matching noble? or was there any jammy lines appearing in the sudo apt update output... The exploration of that output is what I'd look at.

Hi, Sorry if I misunderstood. I see both jammy and nobel in the list and it gave me a warning as well. Here is the warning:
1120 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://packages.openvpn.net/openvpn3/debian jammy InRelease' does not seem to provide it (sources.list entry misspelt?)

This question is similar to: How to fix broken 24.04.1 LTS upgrade which has missing software?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please copy paste the output of the commands as text instead of screnshot

I tried copy and pasting it first but it didn't allow me saying it's too long that's why I put the screenshot. I have also tried that link but it didn't work. I can't remember exactly what was the problem but it didn't work and almost ruined the repository.

I have tried that link again. First of all, there is no ubuntu.sources . Second when I run sudo apt full-upgrade it gives me this error:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
nautilus : Breaks: nautilus-share (< 0.7.3-2ubuntu7~) but 0.7.3-2ubuntu6 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

In your last comment you mention nautilus-share | 0.7.3-2ubuntu6   | jammy             | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x which is a 22.04 package & not what you'd expect IF your sources are correct & match a noble or 24.04 system..  Check your sources   (/etc/apt/sources.list and files within /etc/apt/sources.list.d/) esp. looking for any missing lines (or lines that are incorrect, such as jammy.. your paste shows a rather modified system)...   Also running apt policy nautilus-share shows what?  it should only show a valid noble source

Thanks everyone for helping. I managed to install and upgrade the gnome to 46. It took me a lot of tries, and I am not exactly sure how I did it. But it is working now. This is what I think I did to solve the issue: I changed jammy to noble in all the files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ and /etc/apt/sources.list and then ran sudo apt update sudo apt full-upgrade sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop^
